# Getting numpy.AxisError: axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 2 ? python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to build a machine learning model :

```
def build_model(model,mlb_estimator,xtrain,ytrain,xtest,ytest):
     clf = mlb_estimator(model)
     clf.fit(xtrain,ytrain)
     clf_predictions = clf.predict(xtest)
     y_test_arg=np.argmax(ytest,axis=2,)
     Y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(Xtest),axis=1)
     print('Confusion Matrix')
     print(confusion_matrix(y_test_arg, Y_pred))
     return result
```

but when running the model i am getting this error:

```
numpy.AxisError: axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 2
```

on line 37 which is 4th line in above  :

```
y_test_arg=np.argmax(ytest,axis=2,)
```

What am i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the third dimension (index 2 when indexing starts in 0) of an array with 2 dimensions. Change `axis=2` by `axis=1`.

Comment: after changing to thi axis =1 getting ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3342, 1), indices imply (3342, 9)

Comment: Can you specify the line in the code where this error is raised?